# Speed of UMat vs Mat in DFT OpenCV TAPI

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, image-processing

I found some interesting results regarding performing the `cv::dft` function on `cv::UMat`s vs `cv::Mat`s. Essentially I found that `UMat`s are actually much slower until images up to 4096x4096. Until then, `cv::Mat` consistently wins. Is this just be cause the dft is not implemented for the TAPI api and only the CV::Mat implementation? The test I ran looks something like this (I used the celero project to create the benchmark):

```
constexpr int num_samples = 2;
constexpr int num_iterations = 10;
constexpr int num_rows = 4096;
constexpr int num_cols = 4096;
cv::UMat a = cv::UMat(num_rows, num_cols, CV_32F);
cv::Mat b = cv::Mat(num_rows, num_cols, CV_32F);

void CreateUMat() { cv::randu(a, 0, 256); }
void CreateMat() { cv::randu(b, 0, 256); }
void DftUMat() {
  CreateUMat();
  cv::dft(a, a);
  cv::idft(a, a, cv::DFT_SCALE | cv::DFT_INVERSE);
}
void DftMat() {
  CreateMat();
  cv::dft(b, b);
  cv::idft(b, b, cv::DFT_SCALE | cv::DFT_INVERSE);
}

BASELINE(UMatBenchmarks, Baseline, num_samples, num_iterations) { DftUMat(); }

BENCHMARK(UMatBenchmarks, NoGPU, num_samples, num_iterations) { DftMat(); }
```

I got the following results:

cv::UMat iterations/sec = 4.51

cv::Mat iterations/sec = 4.70

for a smaller image, say 1024x1024 I got the following results:

cv::UMat iterations/sec = 63.21

cv::Mat iterations/sec = 85.83

From these results, you can see that there is almost no advantage to using UMat for large images sizes and there is especially no advantage on smaller images. This surprises me because I got *significant* speed ups with `cv::matchTemplate` when switching to the OpenCV TAPI. My guess is that `cv::dft` has not been implemented in with OpenCL, but is this truly the case? Is the DFT just a **not** good algorithm to offload to the GPUS? Thanks!

Comment: `cv::dft` definitely has OpenCL implementation, but it may has no advantages on some devices (it initially optimized for Intel integrated GPU). What GPU do you use? Also please note that you measure initialization step, and for `UMat` it may be very slow.

Comment: You are right that creating a `cv::UMat` is slower, but from the experiments I've been running, the difference is almost negligible. Especially when running `cv::matchTemplate` because I get almost 400x speed-up by using a `cv::UMat`. The GPU I am running is a AMD Radeon R9 M370X.

Comment: You may try to build opencv with clMath library support. This library contains OpenCL implementation for AMD GPUs. OpenCV has wrapper for it (please look for `WITH_OPENCLAMDFFT` cmake option).

Comment: I can give that a shot. I haven't looked under the hood yet, but I am surprised that the `cv::matchTemplate` function wouldn't use the `cv::dft` function. Maybe they just do a convolution? I'll have to poke around.

Comment: `cv::matchTemplate` uses `cv::dft` only when template size is larger 18*18. For smaller templates it performs naive convolution using custom OpenCL kernels.

Comment: Shoot, my templates have been 17*17. I'll crank that up and rerun my benchmarks.